# Rx Subscribe before Observable created

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, event-bus

In the project, there are many modules. Each module may want to receive data emitted from other module/modules.

The problem trying to solve is, when we subscribe an observable A, this observable may have not been created yet. To solve this problem, two approaches are discussed:

1. Have a Observable Registry singleton. Every time when an observable is ready, put a  pair into the Registry, and notify all modules that Registry changed. Each module will listen to this notification, and decide if it is a change it interested. If it is notified that the observable is ready, subscribe it. If the observable is removed, update the registry, delete corresponding pair, and notify modules, module unsubscribe it.
2. Rx implemented [event bus](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/). Take use of [Subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject): create a singleton Subject, then whenever an event or data or item need to be emitted, emit it from this subject. In your subscriber, you only subscribe on specific event, by using a filter on the subject.

The first approach looks very straightforward, and I cannot tell why it's not good. But it just doesn't look scalable to me. The second approach is the recommended way to replace otto/eventbus with Rx.

Any thoughts on these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

For me the first approach is not that simple and too much to handle. The subscribers can subscribe to a topic and start receiving events whenever there is one for that topic and they would not know if there is a new event source as they don't care.

I use extended variant of version 2, which is [RxHub library](https://github.com/apptik/rxHub). It is quite flexible as allows different behavior per topic/tag.